# Get a property value of multiple IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have four IQueryable:

```
IQueryable<X1> x1; 
IQueryable<X2> x2; 
IQueryable<X3> x3; 
IQueryable<X4> x4;
```

All X objects have a common property, `CodeId`. For example X1 is:

```
public class X1 {
  public Int32 CodeId { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using Linq to Entities how to get all CodeIds in X1, X2, X3 and X4?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want, but if you want a list with all the CodeIds you can:

```
var codeIds = (from s in x1 select s.CodeId)
            .Union(from s in x2 select s.CodeId)
            .Union(from s in x3 select s.CodeId)
            .Union(from s in x4 select s.CodeId)
            .ToList();
```